# Alternative to using dd(get_defined_vars()) to debug Laravel blade templates in VSCODE

Tags: templates, debugging, visual-studio-code, laravel-blade

Are there other ways to debug blade templates outside of using dd(get_defined_vars())

Answer (score 1):

Add a breakpoint in the compiled view as an alternative to using dd(get_defined_vars()) in your raw blade template.

phpstorm already does this in the template but that is not the case for VSCODE.

1. Let's says you have a blade template:
   **...\views\partials\admin\sidebar.blade.php**
2. execute this command in a tinker terminal:
   **sha1(View('partials.admin.sidebar')->getPath())**
3. You will get output like: "9fc9e411b5b0760b70b38864534c90efa26568b7"

That will be name of the compiled view.  The file is in the **storage\framework\views** directory.

Now you can add your breakpoint(s) in that file but be carful not to make any edits.